# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql

Following is my python code:

```
def update_product(self,code,name,weight,stock,sold,order,purchase):
        content = self.ids.scrn_product_contents
        content.clear_widgets()
        code = hashlib.sha256(code.encode()).hexdigest()
        
        sql = 'UPDATE stocks SET product_code=%s,product_name=%s,product_weight=%s,in_stock=%s,sold=%s,order=%s,last_purchase=%s WHERE product_code=%s'
        values =[code,name,weight,stock,sold,order,purchase]

        self.mycursor.execute(sql,values)
        self.mydb.commit()
    
        prodz = self.get_products()
        stocktable = DataTable(table=prodz)
        content.add_widget(stocktable)
```

This is my code.

and this is error

```
"Not enough parameters for the SQL statement")
 mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement
```

I am getting the following error and need help in getting rid of this error, Please.

Comment: Are you missing the value for the product code?

Answer (score 0):

You have 8 `%s` placeholders in the query, but only 7 values in `values`. You're missing the value for `where product_code=%s`.

There's also no need to set `product_code`, since you'll just be setting it back to the same value it already has.

So change it to:

```
sql = '''UPDATE stocks 
        SET product_name=%s,product_weight=%s,in_stock=%s,sold=%s,`order`=%s,last_purchase=%s 
        WHERE product_code=%s'''
values =[name,weight,stock,sold,order,purchase,code]
```

`order` is a reserved wors, you need to escape it with backticks or rename the column.

Comment: thank you for you attention dear Barmar. I tried and it came back to me like this error:
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order='',last_purchase='' WHERE product_code='f791f9fc22abd4f10f0e16d2e7e9366868' at line 1

Comment: `order` is a reserved word it needs to be escaped.